# How to capture the "Stay on Page" button for unsaved changes in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, modal-dialog

I'm working on an application by where I need to be able to detect when the user receives the modal dialog:

> This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved

I also want it to press the "Stay on Page" button. Is this possible with JavaScript?

I've looked through other threads that seem to talk about exiting the page but I actually want to perform some processing as soon as they press the "Stay on Page" button.

Do we have access to these buttons on this dialog - if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to intercept the user trying to leave your page (either by closing the browser tab or navigating away), you may use `window.onbeforeunload`. Depening on the browser, the string returned from that function might be displayed on the navigation confirmation dialog.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  return 'Your data will be lost if you leave now. Are you sure?';
};
```

Unfortuantely, there's no way to get a confirmation out of this dialog as it is browser-controlled.

You might however set yourself a flag inside that function and then react if the user does not leave the page:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  userWantsToLeave = true;
  return 'Your data will be lost if you leave now. Are you sure?';
};

window.onfocus = function() {
  if(userWantsToLeave) {
    // user attempted leaving but changed its mind, do actions here
    userWantsToLeave = false;
  }
}
```

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ec8mtj51/

**Edit:** as stated on the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) for `WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload`, the string you return from the onbeforeunload is no longer presented to the user:

> Starting with Firefox 44, Chrome 51, Opera 38 and Safari 9.1, a generic string not under the control of the webpage will be shown instead of the returned string. For example, Firefox displays the string "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved."

Comment: Thanks Gavino but just another question, is it possible to perform an onfocus on a iframe id window?

Comment: I think it works the same way - if you put the code on the loaded iframe it should get triggered when the user leaves the page

Answer (score 0):

You can see this ->

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Confirm Box</h2>


<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var txt;
    if (confirm("Press a button!")) {
        txt = "You pressed OK!";
    } else {
        txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my question. I am talking about the Firefox modal that appears that prompts you that you have made a change to your data and warns you to Leave page or Stay on Page. It is these buttons I want to capture. Does this make sense? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the confirmation popup on an event listener (in my case i was getting it on a drop event), `event.preventDefault();` might help you